# program is not printing at right points although the coordinates are correct

Tags: c++

I want to build a program that stimulate the behavior of a projectile motion. I have checked the coordinates (x, y) which are correct but the compiler is not printing at right coordinates resulting in an inverted projectile motion(swing like motion)
the file "myconsole.h"is working correctly I have checked it separately.
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <windows.h>
#include "myconsole.h"
using namespace std;

int coordinate(int theta, float v, float g, float initialheight, float x)     //function to calculate y coordinate. it accepts x and produces y
{
    float  y = ((initialheight + (x * tan(theta))) - (( g * (x * x))/(2 * (powf((v * cos(theta)), 2)))));//formula
    return y;
}
int main()
{
    float initialheight = 0;
    int  y = 0;
    int x = 0;
    float v = 0;
    int theta =0;
    float g = 9.81;
    cout<<"Enter the following Information"<<endl;
    cout<<"Angle (theta) = ";
    cin>>theta;
    cout<<"Initial Velocity (V) = ";
    cin>>v;
    cout<<"Initial height = ";
    cin>>initialheight;

        float sq = 2*g*initialheight;//just for simplification
        float sqroot = powf(v * (sin(theta)), 2);//just for simplification
    float d = ((v * (cos(theta))/g)*((v * (sin(theta))+ sqrt(sqroot + sq))));
    /*equation to calculate total distance covered
    by the projectile. I started x from 0 and add 1 to it till it reaches d.for every value of x we get the 
    corisponding value of y from function coordinate.*/

    ClearScreen();
    while(x <= d)//loop to increment x

        {
            y = coordinate(theta, v, g, initialheight, x);

            PlaceCursor(x, y);   //using function from console.h and placing the cursor at (x, y) position
            cout<<"*";

            /*although the coordinates are stimulating the correct behavior of projectile but "* " are printing 
            an inverted projectile*/

            x++;
        }
        system("pause");
        return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: As you haven't stated what you've done to try to fix it, why not check your coordinate function...

Comment: i have checked the coordinate function using break points.

Comment: on screen, a greater y value is downwards, not upwards.

Comment: so what should i do now . formula cannot be changed because it is a mathematical formula considering conventional x and y axis.@NathanOliver

Comment: Taking what I wrote about y increasing moving downwards, which way does the "conventional y axis" increase? Upwards or downwards? i.e. Modify the formula to take this into account

Comment: Fundamental rule of physics: you must understand what the symbols stand for. In conventional 2D projectile problems, **Y** increases *upward*, but on your screen `y` increases *downward*, so you cannot treat them as the same quantity and expect the results to look right. Fundamental rule of coding: simplify. Try setting `g=0` and working without gravity, until you get things working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the coordinate system for a console window starts at 0,0 in the top left and y increases *down* the window. Your code is correct, the graph itself is inverted because that's how the coords work.

I changed your code like this to get the desired result:

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbiInfo; 
HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo (hStdout, &csbiInfo);
int winheight = csbiInfo.dwSize.Y ;

system("cls");
while(x <= d)//loop to increment x

    {
        y = coordinate(theta, v, g, initialheight, x);

        COORD pos;
        pos.X = x;
        pos.Y = winheight -y; 
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout, pos);

        cout<<"*";
```

Comment: This is no way answers the question. You just wrote a comment of mine as an answer. The code is not correct as it does not show what the coder wants

Comment: i have already stated that i want to draw a projectile (parabolic) motion.how you can say that  it does not show what the coder wants @NathanOliver

Comment: actually my knowledge about c++ is at bottom level . if you don't mind can you explain in simple words what you have done in this code . i ll try to edit    it my self...

Answer (score 0):

Without coding it up, this should fix it, change the value of gravity to a negative value in your equation as it's pulling in the opposite direction to your projectile.